# css horizontal navigation question

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a small question about a certain css navigation technique where an end list item is shoved all the way to the left or right.  Look at the light blue navigation above to see an example of what I am talking about.  The light blue navigation has 1 list item which is shoved all the way to the right.  How do I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two navigation menus wrapped in their own div. One is floated left the other "Ask Question" is floated to the right. Both are within a div with an ID hmenus that has a width set. You can view the elements and styles using Chrome developer tool, firebug or just view the source and follow the CSS styles.